# Linking my stylesheet without the root so can use the folder anywhere

Tags: html, css, directory, stylesheet, root

I  linked my stylesheet `customstyle.css` to my `index.html` but when i copy the folder to another drive the stylesheet wont get linked how do i overcome this problem as i have to send the folder to another person

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\healthplus\style.css">
```

Comment: Why not use a relative path?

Comment: @jeffcarey can u help i dont know

Comment: Can you paste the line where you include the stylesheet into your question?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="D:\healthplus\style.css"> @jeffcarey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `index.html` and `customstyle.css` are in the same folder. Then in index.html you should link to your stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="customstyle.css">
```

This is a relative path because it doesn't start with a `/`